# Does windows support link system call?

Tags: windows, hardlink

In linux&unix we can call link(name1, name2) to make name1 and name2 to reference to the same inode, I wonder does windows platform support this? Thank you.

Comment: Windows has CreateHardLink().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think CreateHardLink() is OK for this.